# Angular ng-model with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Having trouble setting the default option in my ng-options/ng-model.

My problem is that while the dropdown is getting populated with the correct options, the default option is blank. This leads me to believe there's something wrong with how I'm doing ng-model. Any help?

I have a table I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over an array:

```
$scope.dumpsters = [
    {id:"1", sub_customer: 'a'},
    {id:"2", sub_customer: 'b'},
    {id:"3", sub_customer: 'c'}
]
```

For simplicity, I have an array of sub_customers that is separate:

```
$scope.subCustomers = [{description:'a'}, {description:'b'}, {description:'c'}];
```

so now in my table, each row has a column that contains this:

```
<select ng-model="d.sub_customer" ng-options="v.description for v in subCustomers" ng-change="updateCustomer(d.sub_customer, d.id)"></select>
```

Comment: what is the unique property in the subCustomer record? Is it description. How do you match a subcustomer with dumpster?

Comment: well, each dumspter has a sub_customer in $scope.dumpsters. that sub_customer is matched with the description in $scope.subCustomers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Another question, say I want to pass "v" from v in subCustomers in my ng-change function, like so:  ng-change="updateCustomer(v, d.id)". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select as` in this case, issue is that with your syntax object references must match. Assuming the matching item is the description field you could just do:

```
<select ng-model="d.sub_customer" 
     ng-options="v.description as v.description for v in subCustomers" 
     ng-change="updateCustomer(d.sub_customer, d.id)"></select>
```

Comment: Another question, say I want to pass "v" from v in subCustomers in my ng-change function, like so: ng-change="updateCustomer(v, d.id)". Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, why not. You can literally pass any expression and they will be evaluated as per its accessiblity in that scope.

Comment: this isn't working  <select ng-model="d.sub_customer" ng-options="v.description as v.description for v in subCustomers" ng-change="updateCustomer(v, d.id)"></select>  as v is undefined in the updateCustomer function. thoguhts?

Comment: @austin809 oh yeah i am sorry you can't access v there.. it is just an iteration variable. Just pass in v.description and you can grab v from there right. I was thinking of ng-repeat when i said it is possible

Comment: hey man, I tried this. But no luck. v and v.description put into the updateCustomer function both come up as undefined.                                                                      <select ng-model="d.sub_customer" ng ng-options="v.description as v.description for v in subCustomers" ng-change="updateCustomer(v.description,d.id)"></select>           Thoughts

Comment: yeah you can't acces it outside. v.description is same as d.sub_customer, so just use it.